# what is the best way to make text in center of header top not left

Tags: php, html, css

How can I make the text logo in the center of the header from top to bottom, not in the center left to right

[image]

```css
header{
background-color: black;   
width:100%;
height: 50px; 
position: fixed;
z-index: 999;
}

.logo
{
float: left;
margin-left:200px;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: bold;
color:
```

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6182661/7873631

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to vertically center a div for all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `float: left`. The best way is to use flexbox containers. You need give to header

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

```css
header{
  background-color: black;   
  width:100%;
  height: 50px; 
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  color: white;
  margin-left:200px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">Some Logo</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

this simple change can make it

```
header{
    background-color: black;   
    width:100%;
    height: 50px; 
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 999;
    }

.logo{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:white
}
```